# SGDClassifier for non linear SVM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm, kernel-density

l have a huge datasets

1) dataset_1= (13000,2048) #13000 samples and 2048 features each
2) dataset_2= (15000,12000)

in order to speed up the computation l used from `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
model=SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", penalty="l2",random_state=42,n_jobs=-1)
```

Than l apply partial_fit on minibatches of 256 samples each as follow :

```
model.partial_fit(X_train_batch, y_train_batch, classes=np.unique(y_train),sample_weight=weights)
```

over `100 epochs`

l save drastically lots of time comparing to a single `LinearSVC()` or `SVC()`

My questions are as follow :

1) How can l use `SGDClassifier` for **non-linear SVM** such as : RBF kernel, triangular kernel, histogram intersection kernel ... ?

2) What the value of Penalty parameter C used in SGDClassifier with loss="hinge" ? Is it the default parameter `C=1.0` as in `LinearSVC()` and `SVC()` ?

2-B) How can l vary `C` values within SGDClassifier ?

Thank you

Comment: (1) SGDClassifier does not support kernels. (you can try kernel-appproximations) (2) The [user-guides](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#mathematical-formulation) each present the formula of the objective. Look it up and compare the part of C vs. alpha (2-B) Just pass it as argument.It's not called C, but alpha.

Comment: @sascha, thank your for your answer. l have another question if you don't mind. to choose the best alpha l need to do cross validation. Is there a way of how to make cross validation with SGDclassifier  ? such like numpy.mean(cross_val_score(clf, data_train, train_labels, cv=5))

Comment: It's working the same as for any other classifier in sklearn (same API). What's wrong with the docs? They are amazing!

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. l'm newbie to sickit learn

Comment: Have a look at [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). But as sascha writes, the documentation is generally really good, and so are the user-guide and quick start. I think that's the easiest way to get started with Scikit-learn.